# Order by title without taking into account 'the' in Wordpress (wp_query)

Tags: sql-order-by, wordpress

I currently have episodes from a TV Show that feature bands playing, so for example I have:

- Moby
- The Dandy Warhols
- The Kooks

My wp_query looks like this:

```
$loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'episodio', 'cat' => '9', 'posts_per_page' => 90, 'orderby' => 'title','order' => 'ASC'  ));
```

But I want to order them like this, alphabetically, without taking into account 'the':

- The Dandy Warhols
- The Kooks
- Moby

There are a lot of records in the database, so it's not very practical and/or efficient to get everything into an array, remove 'the', order again and then going through the array to display the data.

Is this possible in WP? Maybe through a filter?

Thanks a lot in advance! :)

Comment: Create another column on table with the Thes scrubbed and return based on ordering of that column

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'episodio', 'cat' => '9', 'posts_per_page' => 90, 'orderby' => 'title','order' => 'DESC'  ));
you will get result post title descending of category 9.
```